# Reading & processing CSV Files individually, outputting results to new individual files

Tags: python, pandas

I am making what i suspect to be a very silly error here but vast majority of what i've found online talks about reading multiple files into a single dataframe or outputting results into a single file which is not my goal here.

**Aim**: read hundreds of CSV files, one by one, filter each one and output the result in a file using the original file's name in the output/result file (e.g. "Processed_<***original_file>.csv****")*, then move on to the next file in the loop, read & filter that, put the results for that in a new output/result file. and so on.

**Problem**: I either run into a problem where only a single result file is produced (from the last read file in the loop) or if i use the code below , having read various SO pages , i get an invalid argument error.

**Error**: OSError: [Error 22] invalid argument: 'c:/users/my Directory/sourceFiles\Processed_c:/users/my Directory/sourceFiles\files1.csv'

I know i'm getting my loop & re-naming wrong at the moment but can't figure out how to do this without loading ALL my csvs into a single dataframe using list & concat and outputting everything into a single result file (which is not my aim) --- i want to output each result file into individual files , which share the name of the original file.

ideally given the size & number of files (700+ each 400mb) involve i rather use Pandas as that seems to be more efficient from what ive learnt so far.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

path = "c:/users/my Directory/"
csvFiles = glob.glob( path + "/sourceFiles/files*")

for files in csvFiles:
     df = pd.read_csv(files, index_col=None, encoding='Latin-1', engine = 'python',     
          error_bad_lines = False)
     df_f = df[df.iloc[:, 2] == "Office"]
     filepath = os.path.join(path,'Processed_'+str(files)+'.csv')

     df_f.to_csv(filepath)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is nice because it shows you exactly what is wrong--your filename for the output save is wrong because the `c:/users/...` is repeated twice and concatenated together.

Try something with `os.path.basename()` to strip file extension and path:

```
fileout = path + '\\' + 'Processed_' + os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(files))[0] + '.csv'
```

And most importantly, test it with a couple print statements to see if your ins and outs are what you expect. Just comment-out the analysis lines.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

path = "c:/users/my Directory/"
csvFiles = glob.glob( path + "/sourceFiles/files*")

for files in csvFiles:
     print(files)
     #df = pd.read_csv(files, index_col=None, encoding='Latin-1', engine = 'python',     
          error_bad_lines = False)
     #df_f = df[df.iloc[:, 2] == "Office"]
     filepath = path + '\\' + 'Processed_' + os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(files))[0] + '.csv'
     print(filepath)
     #df_f.to_csv(filepath)
```